# S3 NotificationConfiguration - unable to validate destination configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to setup an S3 bucket which notifies a Lambda function when a new object is created.

The stack below works fine but I want to added the `SourceArn` to the Lambda permission, following best practices.

There's some literature on this which suggests the way to do it is via a string rather than `Fn::GetAtt/Arn` -

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-circular-dependency-cloudformation/

But if I uncomment the relevant `SourceArn` line and redeploy, I get -

```
Unable to validate the following destination configurations (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: TBZDEVZ1HVD9EN0Q; S3 Extended Request ID: gL3CRz6UayvHup5i5oC4+/RMm0p1oRaRrPVtfZrykeAaJ1BVuhNSKkqxQ8TL5sy749d9PtbMOEQ=; Proxy: null)
```

Ho hum. Looking at the article again, I see that `MyBucket` needs to depend on `MyBucketFunctionPermission` - but if I uncomment that and redeploy I now get -

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Circular dependency between resources: [MyBucketFunctionPermission, MyBucket]
```

This is some fresh circle of hell. Am I missing something from the article or is there some other combination of `SourceArn` format + `DependsOn` that would get this to work ?

TIA.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Outputs: {}
Parameters: {}
Resources:
  MyBucket:
    #  DependsOn:
    #  - MyBucketFunctionPermission
    Properties:
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
        - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          Function:
            Fn::GetAtt:
            - MyBucketFunction
            - Arn
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  MyBucketFunction:
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: "def handler(event, context):\n  print (event)"
      Handler: index.handler
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - MyBucketRole
        - Arn
      Runtime: "python3.8"
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  MyBucketFunctionPermission:
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName:
        Ref: MyBucketFunction
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      #  SourceArn:
      #    Fn::Sub: arn:aws:s3:::${MyBucket}
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  MyBucketRole:
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Action: sts:AssumeRole
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
        Version: '2012-10-17'
      Policies:
      - PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Action: logs:*
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: '*'
          Version: '2012-10-17'
        PolicyName:
          Fn::Sub: my-bucket-role-policy-1234567890
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing seemingly wrong with your template. It works fine, at least for me. But a **race condition** is possible between `MyBucket` and `MyBucketFunctionPermission`. Thus, protect against this, you have to use `DependsOn`. But for that to work you have to **explicitly set your bucket name**. For example:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Outputs: {}
Parameters: {}
Resources:
  MyBucket:
    DependsOn:
     - MyBucketFunctionPermission
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub "my-bucket-323323-${AWS::StackName}-${AWS::Region}"
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
        - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          Function:
            Fn::GetAtt:
            - MyBucketFunction
            - Arn
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  MyBucketFunction:
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: "def handler(event, context):\n  print (event)"
      Handler: index.handler
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - MyBucketRole
        - Arn
      Runtime: "python3.8"
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  MyBucketFunctionPermission:
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName:
        Ref: MyBucketFunction
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-323323-${AWS::StackName}-${AWS::Region}"
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  MyBucketRole:
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Action: sts:AssumeRole
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
        Version: '2012-10-17'
      Policies:
      - PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Action: logs:*
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: '*'
          Version: '2012-10-17'
        PolicyName:
          Fn::Sub: my-bucket-role-policy-1234567890
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
```

Comment: Didn't know u had to name bucket!

Comment: @Justin In many cases you don't need, but here knowing the name breaks circular dependency. They use similar thing in the link you provided.